# Javascript: + 1 Limit for Counter/Conditional Statement

Tags: javascript, limit, counter

In my javascript game i have a function that is called every 0.1 seconds with setInterval:

```
updateTimerID = setInterval(function(e) {checkProgress();}, 100);
```

I store a users score in a variable and have a conditional statement inside the `checkProgress` function which checks when my slider x position falls between 45 - 48:

```
var score = 0;

function checkProgress(){

    if( slider_1.x => 45 && slider_1.x <= 48 ) {
        score = score + 1
    }

}
```

I then increase the score variable by one when this happens. The problem i have is i only want the score to be updated by 1 every time, not everytime - so with my function being called every .1 seconds - at the moment my score is adding at least 3 each time

```
    if( slider_1.x => 50 && slider_1.x <= 60 ) {
        score ++;
    }
```

Can i limit it to 1 each time?

Comment: "i only want the score to be updated by 1 every time, not everytime"... sorry, what?

Comment: You meant to say on each `checkProgress()` call, the score is increasing thrice, is it?

Comment: Unrelated tip: you can just write `setInterval(checkProgress, 100);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe?:

```
var isOver = false;

function checkProgress(){
    if( slider_1.x => 45 && slider_1.x <= 48 && !isOver ) {
        score = score + 1;
        isOver = true;
    } else if( slider_1.x < 45 && slider_1.x > 48 ) {
        isOver = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I went with this one in the end, now works as i wanted

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by storing the score update time at a variable than substract it from current time to look for the time passed from last update is greater than 1 second

```
 var score = 0;
 var last_update =0;
    function checkProgress(){

        if( slider_1.x => 45 && slider_1.x <= 48 && ((new Date().getTime()-last_update) > 1000) ) {
            score = score + 1
            last_update=new Date().getTime();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do the trick

```
var score = 0;
var inc = true;

function checkProgress(){

    if( slider_1.x => 45 && slider_1.x <= 48 ) {
        if(inc)
        {
            score = score + 1
            inc = false;
        }
    }
    if(slider_1.x < 45 || slider_1.x > 48)
    {
        inc = true;
    }
}
```